# How to calculate the number of days remaining for another date

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

How to import a date from view and calculate the number of days remaining for another date?

Here is the solution I tried but it's not working:

```
class saisir_soumi(osv.osv):
    _name='saisir.soumi' 

    def compa_date(self,cr,uid,ids,args,fields,context=None):       
        r = {}
        date_format = "%D/%M/%Y"
        joining_date = 'date_depot'
        current_date = '29/04/2016 02:02:02'# current date 
        d1 = datetime.strptime(joining_date, date_format)
        d2 = datetime.strptime(current_date, date_format)
        diff = current_date - datetime.date.today()  
        return diff.days

    _rec_name = 'NumOffre'

    _columns = {
        'NumOffre' : fields.char('N° Offre',required=True),
        'organisme_s' : fields.char('Organisme',required=True),
        'date_depot' : fields.datetime('Date dépot de soumission'), # the date to be seized and used for its difference with current date( today)
        'jrestant': fields.function(compa_date,string='Jours restant')
        }
    _sql_constraints = [
        ('uniq_NumOffre', 'unique(NumOffre,id)', "numero offre doit resté unique !"),
        ]
```

Comment: using _columns = {} is old for odoo 8, its odoo 7 style. just saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to do it properly:

- specify correct date/time format
- parse datetime from string
- substract the same data types: `datetime - datetime`

Code:

```
In [68]: current_date = '29/04/2016 02:02:02'

In [69]: date_format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'

In [70]: (datetime.datetime.strptime(current_date, date_format) - datetime.datetime.now()).days
Out[70]: 5
```